# Test influence of one variable on another

Tags: python, r, regression, finance, analysis

I want to test if a specific score of a company has an influence on financial returns of that company.

How can I test this influence in Python or R?

I tried the following in R:

```
fm <-lm(X$Return ~ X$Score ,data = X) 
summary(Return.lm)
```

But i get strange results, which cannot be correct.. How can I do that?

Comment: What makes you think the results cannot be correct? What is strange about them?

Comment: You are using the formula interface to `lm`, so you do not use the `$` notation to access the variables. And your code does not define a variable `Return.lm`. Try instead: `fm <- lm(Return ~ Score, data = X)`, then `summary(fm)`.

Comment: A couple notes: (a) the point of the `data` argument is so that you don't have to use `data$` in the formula. Simplify to `lm(Return ~ Score ,data = X)`. (b) Your model is called `fm`, but you look at the summary of `Return.lm`? Typo in the question or bug in your code?

Comment: I think it is not correct, becuase I get a adjusted R_squared of  0.0008.. This influence ist tested in a variety of studies and nowhere the R_squared is such a small number..

Comment: Well, if adjusted R squared is how you want to measure influence, `lm` is a great method to calculate it. Maybe there's a problem with your data.